# CS1580 fired with a paramater that is generic and nullable (xml doc)

Tags: visual-studio-2019, .net-core-2.0, xml-documentation, c#-7.3

I'm using VS2019 16.1.1 (in VS2017 15.9.12 this does not happen)

I have method with this definition:

```
public static bool HasValue<T>(this T? source) where T : struct
```

and in a xml doc I have this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Internally uses <see cref="TypeValidations.HasValue{T}(T?)"/>.
/// </summary>
```

In VS2019 this fires the error:

```
Error   CS1580  Invalid type for parameter T? in XML comment cref attribute: 'TypeValidations.HasValue{T}(T?)'
```

If I change the documentation to `TypeValidations.HasValue{T}(Nullable{T})`  now I got an analyzer error (SA1125) telling me that I should use the shorthand notation for nullable types.

Is there a "standard" way to refer to nullable types in the XML documentation that not generate an error in the analyzers or the compiler?

Edit:
[repo code](https://github.com/jzamudio/CS1580)

Comment: Does `public static bool HasValue<T>(this T? source)` even compile? Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: added link to a repo in github, in this case T has a struct constraint

Comment: Which StyleCop are you using?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FxCopAnalyzers 2.9.2 and StyleCop.Analyzers 1.1.118

Comment: Try opening issues at https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/ and https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers.